# db_insert() execute() without auto_increment primary key is returning 0

Tags: database

I'm trying to determine whether a database insert query was successful or not by checking the return value of `execute()`, but it seems to be returning `0` even though I can see the data has been inserted into the database. The table I'm adding data to has a primary key but it's not set to auto increment.

```
$result = db_insert('my_table')
                    ->fields(array(
                      'user_id' => $user_id,
                      'my_value' => $num,
                    ))
                    ->execute();
print_r($result); //Prints 0, even when successful
```

How can I check to see if the `db_insert()` was successful or not if I'm not using an auto increment primary key?

Many thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That makes sense - if you haven't got an auto-increment field on the table, then you already *have* the ID that you're inserting, so it would make no sense for an arbitrary column (or primary key, or whatever) value to be returned by PDO.

If the query *fails* it will throw an exception. That's the best (probably only) way to check that the insert was successful in your case, short of running a separate query.

```
try {
  db_insert('...')->execute();
  // No exception thrown; PDO thinks the record was inserted correctly.
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
  // Query failed; recover based on $e->getMessage()
}
```

Comment: Actually, I forced the query to fail and it threw an exception so this makes perfect sense. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: I suppose the `try` clause should include only the final `->execute()` part at least while developing the module.  Otherwise if a `PDOException` error is raised due to another cause during `db_insert()` etc before `->execute()`, that is too caught by the `catch` clause, which could confuse the developer.  Just a note.